# Script for saving multiple .doc files in multiple pages

Tags: file, ms-word

I have 150 .doc (Microsoft Word) files and each one is made by 6 pages.
I would like to save every single file into 3 files, the first is made page 1-2, the second 3-4 and the third 5-6.
The best could be to loop this operation, so with one script i can process all the 150 files.
It doesn't matter if the output is .doc or PDF.
Is there a way to do this?
Once a did a similar splitting operation manually and it took many hours, so i would like to take a shortcut.

Thank you so much,
M.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use python to read each document and save it a temporal file or stream and later re-write the doc file.

Example:

```
one_doc = open('1.docx', 'rb')
two_doc = open('2.docx', 'rb') 
three_doc = open('3.docx', 'rb')

lines_one = one_doc.readlines()
lines_two = two_doc.readlines()
lines_three = three_doc.readlines() 

file = open("C:\myfile.doc","w")
file.writelines(lines_one)
file.writelines(lines_two)
file.writelines(lines_three)

file.close()
```

http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html

For the record perhaps you can count the lines and divide it if you need to cut in some specific page.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I have found also another way: 
What i needed was a PDF output, so first of all i converted all the .doc into pdf following this guide https://igikorn.com/batch-convert-word-documents-pdf/
Thank i found the tool "pdftk"( https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/ ) that allows to slice documents with many options